# How to fix .Net Runtime unhandled exception

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I had a function which I need to Refresh the data grid view. When I deploy the program it automatically close the program.

I have a MSSQL Server in my side. I tried to fix my function several times but it only works fine in my environment.

Here is my code.

```
private async void RefreshDataGrid()
        {
            Console.Write(_workstation);

            bool uiMarshal = DGView.InvokeRequired;
            var cards = (from view in _database.RandomCheckViews
                        where view.Workstation == _workstation
                        && view.Client_Name == _clientName
                        orderby view.ID
                        select view).ToList();
            if (uiMarshal)
            {
                DGView.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    DGView.DataSource = cards;
                    DGView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow cardData in DGView.Rows)
                        if (cardData.Cells["Result"].Value.ToString() == "Failed")
                            cardData.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

                    DGView.Refresh();
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                await Task.Run(() => DGView.DataSource = cards);
                await Task.Run(() => DGView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);

                foreach (DataGridViewRow cardData in DGView.Rows)
                    if (cardData.Cells["Result"].Value.ToString() == "Failed")
                        cardData.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                await Task.Run(() => DGView.Refresh());
            }
        }
```

After I checked several times on our deployment pc, here what I got on Windows Event Viewer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Events><Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='.NET Runtime'/><EventID Qualifiers='0'>1026</EventID><Level>2</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2019-10-29T06:24:24.000000000Z'/><EventRecordID>47775</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>EMV53.dzpemv.net</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>Application: COM_Caller_CS.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.&lt;ThrowAsync&gt;b__5(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
</Data></EventData><RenderingInfo Culture='en-US'><Message>Application: COM_Caller_CS.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.&lt;ThrowAsync&gt;b__5(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
</Message><Level>Error</Level><Task></Task><Opcode>Info</Opcode><Channel></Channel><Provider></Provider><Keywords><Keyword>Classic</Keyword></Keywords></RenderingInfo></Event></Events>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Looking at your code, so many other questions pops up.

Answer (score 0):

had a similar problem some time ago, if i remember correctly it was a problem with async void, which you are using aswell.

Try with using a Task

```
private async Task RefreshDataGrid()
```